# Backbone this.el and events not working when I render my templates from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

When I'm appending my template to the body, the **el** and **$el** do not work. For example, consider this view that renders the template onto the body:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: "#main-menu",
   initialize: function(){
      this.render();
   },
   events: {
      "click": "clickHandler"
   },
   render: function(){
      $("body").append( '<div id="main-menu" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;"></div>' );
   },
   clickHandler: function(){
    alert("test");
   }
});
```

I render the div containing the **#main-menu** element after it's already defined for the **el**. Whenever I try to use the **el** or any of the events it doesn't work. An option would be to set the **el** to **body** but for some reason that seems wrong to me since that's not really my element and I would have to write **#main-menu** in all the click handlers.

Thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating your view's `element` inside of the `render` function. Append the element to the body in the code where you initialize the view and then initialize the view with `myView = new MyView({el: $('#main')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically telling backbone that your `el` is the element with id **main-menu** that should already exist in the page. However you are adding the element with that id in the render function! You would need to manually reset the view element with `this.setElement($("#main-menu"));` which is quite ugly.

You have 2 options:

- Create and add to the page the `main-menu` element before the view is created, which allows you to define your view in a similar way as you had:

  ```
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: "#main-menu",
      initialize: function(){
          this.render();
      },
      events: {
          "click": "clickHandler"
      },
      render: function(){
          this.$el.append('<p>Some menu contents</p>' );
      },
      clickHandler: function(){
          alert("test");
      }
  });

  $("body").append( '<div id="main-menu"></div>');
  var view = new MyView();
  ```

  You can check it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htdomme5/1/)
- Don´t set el in your view and let backbone to create an element taking into account the `id`, `tagName`, `className` and `attributes` properties of your view. Then once your view is created, you can insert its `$el` into the page.

  ```
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
      id: "main-menu",
      initialize: function(){
          this.render();
      },
      events: {
          "click": "clickHandler"
      },
      render: function(){
          this.$el.append('<p>Some menu contents</p>');
      },
      clickHandler: function(){
          alert("test");
      }    
  });

  var view = new MyView();
  $("body").append(view.$el);
  ```

  You can give it a try on [this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re5z6aof/)

Comment: Option 2... Beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behavoir, please review this code :

```
this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
this.el = this.$el[0];
```

This is Backbone internal view code. the el element should be a exist element in the DOM tree. 
In my opinin, for this task You shoud create parent/child view. For example create two view and render one of inner another.